# Qt - WINDOWS - Bluetooth Low Energy working?

Tags: windows, qt, bluetooth

I try to connect to a BLE device using Qt. But I don't know why my used tool doesn't find my device.

Used tool: https://github.com/Gawhary/Qt-BLE-Tester

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt don't suport bluetooth BLE on windows. doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-le-overview.html only on mac and linux.
If you want BLE suport look here. https://forum.qt.io/topic/60288/does-qt-support-bluetooth-low-energy-under-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Qt supports Bluetooth Low Energy on Windows 10 as Central when developing UWP (WinRT) Apps since [Qt5.8](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.8)

There is no Bluetooth Low Energy support for classic Windows applications as specified on their [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html).